# Convert Mortice Lock to Cylindrical Lock

Tags: wood, doors

Currently I have a mortice lock. My condo has rules on the esthetic looks of the lock. I wanted to change the lock to keyless and found something similar. However it's a cylindrical lock which the package says "retrofittable".  My question is: Is it possible to just change the handles?

I have attached the photos. 1st photo is the original lock. 2nd photo is what I plan to change to. [image: 1st photo original mortice lock]
[image: 2nd photo keyless lock]

Comment: Most multi-family dwellings require that the building (often the superintendent) have access to the apartment in case of emergencies (leaks, etc.). Have you considered this in your plans?

Comment: As an aside, the existing lock is vastly more secure than the thing you want to replace it with. If you went to all the trouble of filling/re-drilling as detailed by @bib, would you have any responsibility to setting it back as it was when you move? (That would be just as much trouble as switching.)

Comment: Yes. I was thinking about that too. Will it be possible to just change the lever (if the spindle fits) without changing the whole mortise or modify the spindle of the keyless to fit into the mortise body?  I noticed that how the lockwood code handle works is thru the spindle. If the right code is enter, the spindle will lock and lets you open the door. Vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no.

The new lock is a cylindrical type that requires a standard hole in the door, usually 2 1/8", set back a certain distance from the edge. Most mortise locks do not have that size hole, so it must be drilled with a hole saw. Also, the mortise mechanism must be removed and the door needs to be filled in where the mortise has been taken out to hold the latch mechanism. A hole for the latch will also have to be drilled into the newly built up edge.

You also need to remove the existing deadbolt from the bottom and replace it with a cylindrical type deadbolt. Again, the hole may be different and the mortise channel must be filled and drilled to hold the bolt mechanism.

None of this is very difficult, but requires the right tools and some patience. Care must be taken, because misdrilled holes in a door are difficult to fix aesthetically.

Comment: Is it possible to just change the lever / handle of the mortice without changing the whole mortise lock. Or modify the Lockwood spindle / lever / handle to fit into the mortise body?  I noticed that the Lockwood code handle works by locking snd unlocking the spindle with the code.

Comment: [This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYzcDCp1Dpc) shows that the lever body is a cylindrical lock type. It is not compatible with a mortise type spindle and lever.

Comment: Thanks Bib, However can you have a look at my video here. I had someone take out the lever handle from the mortise and see if the new code handle can fit. And it can. But the problem is the mounting hole/screw on the roses. The mounting hole/screw on the mortise is horizontal while the code handle is vertical.  (Pls see video). My question is:  is there a way to change the position of the mounting hole/screw on the lever roses? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5DhlPZnPA4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Lever handles are available for some (not all) recently manufactured mortise sets. Asking a locksmith to look that up for your specific lockset is more likely to find a useful solution than asking here without full details about the lockset.